# rsh connection from Linux to HP times out

Tags: linux, hp-ux, rsh

I added Linux boxes to /etc/hosts.equiv and .rhosts file for rsh connectivity to an HP box.
I am able to do rsh as root from Linux to HP. But if I run in a root shell as different user connection times out. Any reason?

Comment: rsh -l <username> <hostid> "hostname"

Answer (score 0):

Try running rsh with the "-l" option to specify username or try

```
rsh user@hostname
```

If you don't it will default to the user you are currently logged in as.

Comment: Also, obligatory finger-wagging about using ssh instead of rsh. *WAG*WAG*

Comment: Cannot use ssh for its complicated to set up in our environment.

Comment: I don't see how ssh could be more complicated to set up than rsh... Thankfully, those are not my servers.